# update chart in chart js without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

i trying to create a chart when users search and it works but the problem when user search again it throw Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use and when i try to destroy it it throw another error says that destroy is not function, I need a way to make the chart change when user serach without the need to reload the page

my code

```
var endpoint = "/api/chart/data";
myform.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  var amount = document.querySelector("#amount").value;
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint + "?name=" + name + "&amount=" + amount,
    success: function (data) {
      labels = data.labels;
      data = data.data;
      console.log("success");
      console.log(name);
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels:labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "# of Votes",
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                },
            ],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    min: -100,
                    max: 100,

                    ticks: {
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
    },
    error:function(){
        console.error('enter valid data')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You never call destroy on the chart anywhere?

Comment: i didn't @LeeLenalee add it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `myChart` variable is declared inside the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_scope) of the AJAX `success` function. The variable only exists within the function body during its execution. When the user performs a new search, the `success` function is invoked again but the initially created `myChart` variable does no longer exist.

You can solve your problem by creating `myChart` at the beginning in the global scope as follows.

```
var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: [], // initialize with an empty array
    datasets: [{
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [], // initialize with an empty array
      ...
});
```

Your event listener and AJAX request would then look as shown below. Note that I set the `labels` and `data` on the existing chart and call `myChart.update()` afterwards. This is cleanest and the most efficient way to deal with new data. For further details, please consult [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/developers/updates.html) from chart.js documentation.

```
var endpoint = "/api/chart/data";
myform.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  var amount = document.querySelector("#amount").value;
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint + "?name=" + name + "&amount=" + amount,
    success: function(data) {
      myChart.data.labels = data.labels;
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data.data;
      myChart.update();
    },
    error: function() {
      console.error('enter valid data')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked @uminder update for the any one who will find the answer useful instead of myChart.data.datasets[0] its myChart.data.datasets[0].data

Comment: @Super sub: I have corrected the error in my answer, thanks for pointing it out!